# Total Rows and Columns Count - Excel Office JS

Tags: excel, office-js

I've been using `getRangeByIndexes` as it seems to be the best way to use numbers to get Ranges in Office-JS. Problem I'm having is that when I need to use entire row/columns, I've resorted to the below. I read up and looks like number of rows/cols hasn't changed in a long time, but I know in vba I used `rows.count` to make sure the code was dynamic, whatever version of Excel it would use the number of rows on a spreadsheet.

Is there anything similar in Office-JS?

```
const Excel_Worksheet_Lengths_Obj = {
    "total_rows": 1048576,
    "total_cols": 16384,
}

var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet()

var Method_Headers_Rng = ws.getRangeByIndexes(0,0,1,Excel_Worksheet_Lengths_Obj.total_cols)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it for you ...

```
const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

let rangeRows = sheet.getRange("A:A").load(["rowCount"]);
let rangeColumns = sheet.getRange("1:1").load(["columnCount"]);

await context.sync();

console.log("Row Count = " + rangeRows.rowCount);
console.log("Column Count = " + rangeColumns.columnCount);
```

Everything relating to the number of rows or columns looks to be done at the range level, not the worksheet level.

Passing in the first column to achieve the number of rows and the first row to achieve the number of columns does the trick.  Not ideal but such is life.

Comment: You never said you wanted something better, you asked for how to do it and I gave you the answer.  I agree, it's not "better" but if Excel changes, it won't mean you have to go back and rehash code.  Also, is the `console.log` comment a joke?!?

Comment: "... to make sure the code was dynamic, whatever version of Excel it would use the number of rows on a spreadsheet" ... I've given you the answer and you don't like it, fine, but you're shooting the messenger mate, speak to Microsoft.  Also, 100's of SO answers each day send the OP down a different path.  You never said anything about not wanting to call sync or that "NO" would've been a better answer.  The words "not ideal but such is life" makes it pretty clear AND I've also provided an approach for others if they so desire.  Again, if you're unhappy, speak to Microsoft.  Sorry for trying!

Comment: I understand your position and sorry if I sounded rude, but I would think your answer would state that its worse then my current approach and that  I'm likely better off the way I'm doing it. From what I read, lrow/lcol hasn't changed since before Office-JS was introduced, so I don't see the benefit of an extra sync. Although syncs can be batched.. so probably could be negligible. Probably won't use it, but worth leaving for community. Thanks